# I want to make a primary key like this SP13-BCS-001. In it sp13-bcs- remains same and only integer should be auto incremented in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, c#-3.0

Primary key should be like this sp13-bcs-001,,,,sp13-bcs-002  etc
integer should be auto incremented

Comment: A more detailed answer might be possible if you told us what database platform you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment and somehow I assumed the question was about SQL Server.  So, this is SQL Server specific.

The best type of primary key is really an `identity` column.  This is convenient in many ways:

- The column has a fixed width (4 or 8 bytes)
- Integers are natural data types for computers
- Indexes (and hence foreign key relationships) are more efficient when based on fixed-width keys
- Identity columns are fast

Those are good reasons for using them as a primary key.  What you want to do is much more complicated.  If *all* keys were exactly 'sp13-bcs-NNN', then I would suggest a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add computed_pk as ('sp13-bcs-' + right('000' + cast(id as varchar(255)), 3));
```

This gives you a computed primary key with the structure that you want.

However, I suspect that the `'sp13-bcs'` is really a prefix that can change.  To implement this as a primary key, you would need a trigger that would count the number of previous values -- and that is really expensive for a simple insert.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a column called ID that is autoincremented like everywhere else
2. Then create a view with `'sp13-bcs-'+RIGHT('000'+cast(ID as varchar(3)),3)` for your id
3. Spend the rest of the time before id goes over 1000 figuring out what you are going to do when it does.

> You could also create an "auto-calculated" column in a table, but that is platform dependent and you didn't say what platform you are using.